# Django RestAPI - only allow access to users data with JWT Authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I have the following API:

Model:

```
class Todo(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")
    text = models.TextField(max_length=450, default="")
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

View:

```
class TodoView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TodoSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        id = self.request.query_params.get("id")
        queryset = Todo.objects.filter(owner__id=id)
        return queryset
```

Serializer:

```
class TodoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Todo
        fields = ("id", "owner", "name", "text", "done")
```

I use `rest_framework_simplejwt` for my tokens and the following path to receive my token:

```
path("api/token/", TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name="token_obtain_pair"),
```

This is the token: `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjE5Mjg4ODAwLCJqdGkiOiJhY2E4MjM5ZGMyZjA0NGE5YWE4NzM3NWZjMDc2NWQ0YSIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjF9.xJ4s971XE0c9iX0Ar1HQSE84u_LbDKLL4iMswYsk2U8`

When I decode it on the jwt.io I can see that it contains the user id:

```
{
  "token_type": "access",
  "exp": 1619288800,
  "jti": "aca8239dc2f044a9aa87375fc0765d4a",
  "user_id": 1
}
```

A request on `http://localhost:8000/todos/?id=1` without the token in my request header does not work (fine!), but with the token, I also can access `http://localhost:8000/todos/?id=2` which is of course undesired. I only want access to `http://localhost:8000/todos/?id=1` (the coresponding `user_id` from the payload)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `get_queryset` method with this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    reque Todo.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

Now anyone can access only own Todo records.

Url should like this `http://localhost:8000/todos/<id>`

Extra:
Don't take `owner` from client. Instead set yourself.
Like below.

```
class TodoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = Todo
        fields = ("id", "owner", "name", "text", "done")
```

Comment: Hm, I get a new error: TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x000002581CE88FA0>.

Comment: @DataMastery Looks like you still use `owner__id` on filter instead of `owner`

Comment: You should also give the type for id in the url is an int `/todos/<int:id>/` but if you are using  `Todo.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)` then no need of passing the id in the URL, so `/todos/`